# Gitosis local filesystem clone

Tags: git, gitosis

I set up gitosis on a server. Cloning and pushing from my laptop works fine. However, I want to make a local clone on the server using my user (not the git user). Gitosis seems to manage the file permissions by itself, making all repos unreadable by others. Is there some better way to get around this than just cloning via ssh to localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding my user to the git group.

Comment: Ooops. Now I can clone, but not push, since group permissions are rx. Any better idea?

Comment: Just cloned over ssh to localhost in the end. Seems there is no better way to do it with gitosis.